HAProxy: need to reset persistent cookie connections
I am using HAProxy for load balance with cookie based session persistence.
Configuration:
backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    cookie SERVER insert indirect nocache
    server node1 localhost:8080 cookie node1
    server node2 localhost:9090 cookie node2
    server node3 localhost:9091 cookie node3
    server node4 localhost:9092 cookie node4
    server node5 localhost:9093 cookie node5
    server node6 localhost:9094 cookie node6

The problem is that I had five servers, perfectly balanced, but I added a new server and sessions are not being rebalanced as I thought they would be. The new server only have a few sessions.
How can I force a rebalance?

Try using maxidle and maxlife params for the cookie statement.
E.g.
cookie SERVER insert indirect nocache maxidle 30m maxlife 8h

See the documentation.

Just curious, why is indirect and maxidle each needed?

Just change:
balance roundrobin

to
balance leastconn


this won't redistribute the already existing associations, which are based on cookies
